# DB Architecture Localizable Strings

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a DB, which is for a news service. News have localizable strings like **title, description, text.**
Now I have a Table **"News"** and a Table **"LocalizableVariables"**.

Entries could look like that:

```
News Table:
ID (PK)  |  thumbnailURL         |  author  | etc.
1        |  www.*.*/picture.jpg  |  John Doe

LocalizableVariables Table (CK = Composite Key):
locale (CK)  |  newsID (CK)  |  name  |  value    
en           |  1            |  title |  "Example"
de           |  1            |  title |  "Beispiel"
fr           |  1            |  title |  "Exemple"
```

Would that be a correct and performant implementation on a relational db like MySQL?
If not, what can I change to get the best result.

Beforehand, the company I am working for, had this idea:

```
News Table (CK = Composite Key):
ID (CK)  |  locale (CK)  |  title     |  etc.
1        |  en           |  "Example"
2        |  de           |  "Beispiel"
```

Would that version be as fast as the other, even if not normalized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither.

```
News Table - contains all language-independent columns:
ID (PK)  |  thumbnailURL         |  author  | etc.
1        |  www.*.*/picture.jpg  |  John Doe

NewsLocalization -- contains all language-dependent column;
has a composite PRIMARY KEY(newsID, locale), no AUTO_INCREMENT:
newsID (CK) |  locale (CK)  |  title     |  etc.
1           |  en           |  "Example"
1           |  de           |  "Beispiel"

SELECT nt..., nl...
    FROM NewsTable AS nt
    JOIN NewsLocalization AS nl  ON nl.newsID = nt.ID AND nl.locale = 'de'
    WHERE nt...
```